# Differentiating HTTP bot traffic from regular users

Tags: http

I run a quite small website and I'd like to have some analytics about the traffic it gets from regular users. And I'd like to continue allowing bots to scrape it. I don't really care enough to invest in trying to detect bad-acting bots masquerading as real users (nor can I think of a reason my site would be the target of such bots).

My quick-and-dirty approach has been to just look at all of the user agents I've received, eyeball which ones seem like bots, and put them in a manually-maintained list. This seems error-prone, and I have to update the list if the various bots ever change their strings, or if a new one discovers my site.

Is there a better approach? In terms of amount of upkeep and error-prone-ness.

I guess this also gets into a broader question: if there doesn't exist a standard way for a good-acting bot to identify itself as such, why not? Have there been proposals to make this a part of some spec?

Comment: You could use a user agent list, [like this](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_type_specific/crawler/). ... Though, I'm under the impression that many analytics packages and services maintain their own lists and already filter bots out for you. E.g., [Google analytics](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.searchenginewatch.com/sew/news/2358054/google-analytics-helps-you-filter-spider-and-bot-traffic/amp/) ...

Comment: Malicious bots are rarely targeting "important" sites, they mostly want to find vulnerable sites to exploit. This means that your small website will most likely receive proportionally less " legitimate" crawler traffic than big, well-referenced sites.

Comment: It's probably easier to make a whitelist of commonly used web browsers than to make a blacklist of bots. If you look only at the name and not the whole user agent string, top 10 will probably make up 95% of your bot traffic.